# Java - get errors propagated from background thread

Tags: java, user-interface, executorservice

I am trying to run a background service as part of my GUI application. I am using an `ExecutorService` and I am getting a `Future` back from it. This code shows what I am doing:

```
 play.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

      service.submit(new Runnable(){ .... } }
 }
```

Now, the submission is happening on the GUI thread, which should propagate exceptions to the main thread. Now, I don't want to block the main thread on `future.get`, but I would rather have some way of checking for the result of the future, so that the exceptions are proapagated to the main thread. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a listener pattern to be notified when the background thread is done. SwingWorker for instance allows for PropertyChangeListeners to listen to the SwingWorker.State state property and you could either do this or roll your own. This is one of my favorite features of a SwingWorker.

An example....

```
  final MySwingWorker mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker(webPageText);
  mySwingWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

     @Override
     public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
        if (pcEvt.getNewValue().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE)) {
           try {
              mySwingWorker.get();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); // this needs to be improved
           } catch (ExecutionException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); // this needs to be improved
           }
        }
     }
  });
  mySwingWorker.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Future.isDone() to see if it has finished, or you can have the background task perform the action e.g.

```
play.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

  service.submit(new Runnable(){ 
     public void run() {
       try {
       // .... 
       } catch(Exception e) {
           SwingUtils.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   handleException(e);
               }
           }
       }
    }
  });
```

Comment: But `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is executed on EDT not the main thread.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Unless it's the EDT the OP is talking about, I don't know why it needs to be passed back to the "main" thread to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an additional thread just to monitor the state of the future:

```
final Future<?> future = service.submit(...);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            future.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            runOnFutureException(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}).start();
```

And somewhere else:

```
public void runOnFutureException(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("future returned an exception");
}
```

Comment: If this is ok, the background thread can make the call. There is no need to add another thread for this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Definitely - it depends where you want to put the exception clutter - my proposal leaves the background class "clean". But both work.